# Should I Write Unit Tests That Check the Default Values of An Object's Properties?

Tags: unit-testing

The question title really says everything, but I'll do my best to clarify things. Let's say I have the following object:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.isAwesome = true;
    // Other methods and property
}
var obj = new MyObject();
```

Now, when writing unit tests against this object, should I write a test that makes sure that the `isAwesome` property defaults to true? Or is that too rigid of a test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only write the test if the variable `isAwesome` is somehow part of the public facing portion of the class. If `isAwesome` just affects the behaviour of the class, test instead for that behavior.

Typically, a variable like that should *not* be part of the public facing portion of the class. For clean code, the least that would be required is that the variable be private and have getter and setter functions. Test those functions.

Comment: Testing trivial getters and setters is also just testing simple language constructs. If a getter or setter does more than just retrieve or modify a value, *then* test it.

Comment: The getters and setters could be more complex. Your unit test are supposed to not know the details of how your class works. But it does need to verify that it is working.

Comment: Yes, they *could* be. If they *are*, then test them. If not, you're testing whether assignment or the `return` construct of the language work.

Comment: You're not supposed to base your tests on how the code is _currently_ set up. Test all public facing functions, trivial or not.

Comment: unit tests are coupled to how it works even though they are actually independent of the implementation.  Having done many coding interviews where I set someone a problem with a defined interface, I'd have a bunch of tests pre done, but then peoples implementations might pass those tests but have weird bugs that the tests don't cover.  It highlights that you will never have a set of tests that will fully test that a function will do what is expected.   So in practical terms you need to test the least amount practical.  The more tests, the less agile, too little tests, more fragile.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a trivial test to write, and if there are significant ramifications if `isAwesome` is false, then why *wouldn't* you write that test?

Think about this - suppose a *different* developer comes by 6 months from now and thinks - "I'll change it so the property is not set in the constructor - let the client decide if `MyObject` is awesome or not".

Now all of the code that expects *every* `MyObject` to be awesome may break.  Wouldn't you want to know that such a change as made so you could decide if it was a valid change or not?

Comment: If this change would only be caught in the unit test for the constructor, then reaching 100% coverage on this particular unit test is the least of the developer's concerns.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the constructor is capable of changing that default value. I don't know what language this is you're writing, so I'll just wing it:

```
function MyObject(stopBeingAwesome) {
    this.isAwesome = true;
    if (stopBeingAwesome) {
        this.isAwesome = false;
    }
}
```

If this is the case, then you can test that logic. Otherwise, you're unit testing *a basic language construct such as assignment*.

Unit tests are supposed to test the contracts of a unit of code. That is, the same input should always result in the same output. In this case, your contract involves `this.isAwesome` being `true` when the object is finished being constructed. However, unless someone changes the implementation of `MyObject` so that `isAwesome` won't be `true`, it's not necessary to test that. And, if someone does change the implementation, they'll have to modify the test too. Worrying about regression at this level means that you're afraid that your other tests won't successfully test the default behavior, and that your coworkers are code saboteurs who will gleefully modify your constructor's default behavior for no apparent reason without telling you and without running your integration test suite.

It may seem like I am against regression tests, but when a build takes 20 minutes on Jenkins, you start to be grateful that you decided *not* to test some things.